# How to autoload PHP namespaces without Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to use this library:
https://github.com/wunderio/docebo-php

However, its not found in Composer, despite it listing the Composer command on the page.

How can I call this library and create a new instance of the `Docebo` class as shown in the example?

```
use Docebo\Docebo;

try {
  $docebo = new Docebo('base_url', 'client_id', 'client_secret', 'username', 'password');
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I attempted to use this library by cloning the github repo, and creating the following:

```
docebo-php/src$ cat test.php
<?php
require_once("Docebo/Docebo.php");

use Docebo\Docebo;

try {
  $docebo = new Docebo('base_url', 'client_id', 'client_secret', 'username', 'password');
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

This just results in:

```
$ php test.php
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Docebo\DoceboInterface' not found in /var/www/www/htdocs/docebo-php/src/Docebo/Docebo.php on line 18
```

Comment: `foreach( glob('Docebo/*') as $docebo ) { require $docebo; }` should work.

Comment: Create a 'basecontroller' and a 'basemodel'. These functions can be extended, so all functions will always be readed. (and use php 7.x)

Comment: @RonnieOosting how can I do this? :/

Comment: @BenM this didnt work. PHP still responds with `Interface 'Docebo\DoceboInterface' not found`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear that are you using any framework or just plain PHP code.

my solution is for plain PHP code:

you can write your own PHP autoloader to include libraries like :

```
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    //class directories
    $directorys = array(
        '/Controllers/',
        '/Libraries/',
    );

    //for each directory
    $ds = "/"; //Directory Seperator
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__); //Get Current file path
    $windir = "\\"; //Windows Directory Seperator
    $path = str_replace($windir, $ds, $dir);

    foreach($directorys as $directory)
    {
        //see if the file exsists
        if(file_exists( $path . $directory . $class_name . '.php'))
        {
            require_once( $path . $directory . $class_name . '.php');
            //only require the class once, so quit after to save effort (if you got more, then name them something else
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Store it as autoload.php in your project root directory, then require it on top of any PHP file you have like:

```
require_once('autoload.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom repository with [`vcs`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) type and install this library using Composer anyway, even if it is not available at Packagist:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/wunderio/docebo-php"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "wunder/docebo-php": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Composer will clone this repo and fetch metadata from it directly.

Note that `vcs` type should be less problematic than [`package`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) type, which has some limitations and should be used only if everything else fails.